# Monitor not turning off when screen saver is on

Tags: 12.04, monitor, screensaver

I installed Ubuntu for the first time 3 weeks ago and I really love it. I have Ubuntu 12.04.
My only problem is that when screen saver is on, it just shows blank screen, and not turning off the monitor, so my monitor is always on.

I have Samsung E2220 - 22".
I looked over the web and I found this command:

```
sudo xset dpms force off
```

This command shuts down my screen so I don't see a reason why the screen saver can't shut it down.

Thanks a lot!
Elad

Answer (score 0):

The screen saver isn't meant to turn it off. It is literally just a blank screen. If you want to turn the screens off, go to `System Settings`, click `Brightness & Lock` then chose how long you want the screen to turn off after from the dropdown.